# Pointers in insert function for Binary Search Tree (BST)

Tags: c, data-structures

This program is a insert function for a binary search tree, I totally understand the concept behind it and everything.. the only thing I don't understand is this line :

```
BTree root = NULL;
```

so as i understand *root* is a pointer that does not point to any thing thats why its NULL , but why its data type is *BTree*, is it not supposed to be *_btree* ? 
I know there is a pointer *Btree but its not a datatype so how is it possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct _btree 
{ 
    int v;
    struct _btree *left, *right; 

} BTreeRec , *BTree;



BTree insert(BTree t, int v)
{ 
    if (t == NULL) {

        t = (BTree)malloc(sizeof(BTreeRec)); t->v = v;
        t->left = t->right = NULL;

    } else if (v < t->v)
        t->left = insert(t->left, v);
    else
        t->right = insert(t->right, v); return t;
}


int main() {

 BTree root = NULL;

}
```

Comment: Aaaand that's why `typedef` pointers are confusing. Please indent your code properly.

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines:

```
typedef struct _btree 
{ int v;
struct _btree *left, *right; 
} BTreeRec , *BTree;
```

are equivalent to:

```
struct _btree { 
     int v;
     struct _btree *left;
     struct _btree *right; 
};
typedef struct _btree   BTreeRec;
typedef struct _btree * BTree;
```

A typedef is like an alias for the name. And the `*` "sticks" with it. Every time your write `BTree` it's the same as `struct _btree *` *with* the star included. So your code is equivalent to:

```
struct _btree *insert(struct _btree *t, int v) {
   if (t == NULL) {
        t = malloc(sizeof(struct _btree));
        t->v = v;
        t->left = NULL;
        t->right = NULL;
   } else if (v < t->v) {
        t->left = insert(t->left, v);
   } else {
        t->right = insert(t->right, v);
   }
   return t;
}

int main() {
   struct _btree *root = NULL;
}
```

Which is 500% more readable and the intention is much more clearer. Code is like a poem - it has to be nice to read it. As a general rule the use of typedef pointers is discouraged (unless you are implementing a specific case like an opaque library where you specifically want to use them). Subjectively: I am on the side that also doesn't like the use of `typedef` to hide a `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

Derived types can be declared via `typedef`. Here it happens at:

```
typedef struct _btree {...} BTreeRec , *BTree;
```

It declares `BTreeRec` as a synonym for `struct _btree`, and `Btree` as a synonym for `struct _btree *`.

So `BTree root = NULL;` is equivalent to:

```
struct _btree *root = NULL;
```